# custom header angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to add a customer header in a request angular js for the first time, but am getting the following error

> angular.js:10671Error: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'x-api-key:' is not a valid HTTP header field name.

Here is my code, at the highest 'app' level:

```
var movieApp = angular.module('movieApp', ['ngAnimate']);

movieApp.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = { 
        'x-api-key:' : 'key'
      };
}])
```

What am i doing wrong/missing/not understanding? How can I add this header to all (or even one) request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error explains, `x-api-key` is not a valid HTTP header field. You can go [here for the official documentation](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), or [look at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). To fix this, you have to pass the api key as parameter in the request body.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. this is for a get request, so I'm assuming a query string would work? I appended the request with ?x-api-key=key and am now getting the following error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load blah?x-api-key=key. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404. (end error) Will setting an origin work or do I have to do JSONP?

Comment: @devdropper87 as the resource you are trying to fetch doesn't have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in response header, you have to look for options such as JSONP.